# How can i use concmath font for math with concrete font for roman?

Tags: fonts

Right now I'm using:

```
\usepackage{concmath}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qhv}
```

Not I want to use `concrete` package but only such that the normalfont and bf font are changed. But it also changes the mathfont. How can I change this to work with the `concmath` font?

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

To just load the text fonts and leave the mathematics alone, use the `beton` package instead.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{beton}

\begin{document}

Some concrete text and normal \( x^2 - y^2 = t \) maths.

\end{document}
```

See the description of the [`concrete` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/concrete?lang=en) on CTAN.

To switch the sans serif font I would then suggest you load on appropriate package, e.g. `helvet`:

[image: Sans serif sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{beton}
\usepackage[scaled=0.92]{helvet}

\begin{document}

Some concrete text and normal \( x^2 - y^2 = t \) maths.

\textsf{Something sans serif.}

\end{document}
```